# Unable to evaluate Match using Apache Poi evaluate

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi, match

I am trying to evaluate formula cell in XSSF Sheet using Apache Poi evaluator.

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
System.out.println(evaluator.evaluate(cell));
```

cell has this formula

```
MATCH(1,('refsheet'!$A$1:$A$10=$C$1)*('refsheet'!$B$1:$B$10>=$D$1),0)
```

And sysout prints Output -

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue [#N/A]
```

A1 - A10, B1 - B10 , C1 and D1 are all numeric

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't understand why I am getting #N/A

Getting correct value in excel sheet

What am I doing wrong

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using? The formula `MATCH(1,('refsheet'!$A$1:$A$10=$C$1)*('refsheet'!$B$1:$B$10>=$D$1),0)` is an array formula. Versions up to `3.17` could not evaluate such array formulas properly. But, even if evaluated, the formula results in `#N/A` if either `'refsheet'!$A$1:$A$10=$C$1` or `'refsheet'!$B$1:$B$10>=$D$1` is not true.

Comment: @Axel Richter I have 3.10, I will try upgrading the version. However both refsheet expressions are true and I get a proper value in ms excel

Comment: @Axel Richter, can you please suggest an alternative perhaps to override evaluation for array formulas. I tried upgrading the version but version upgrade is impacting a lot of other things in the application as version 4 had major changes. Any suggestions if possible. I appreciate your comment

Comment: @Axel Richter I updated the pom.xml with 4.1.2, built it, but still getting same output #N/A, also updated question with current pom.
What am I doing wrong? Both refsheet expressions definitely return true for few rows, checked again with individual output

Comment: Cannot reproducing. For me `apache poi 4.1.2` evaluates the formula `=MATCH(1,(refsheet!$A$1:$A$10=$C$1)*(refsheet!$B$1:$B$10>=$D$1),0)` correct. Please show a reproducible example (complete code, values in `refsheet!$A$1:$A$10`, `refsheet!$B$1:$B$10`, `$C$1` and `$D$1`). Also make sure, the `apache poi 4.1.2` really gets used. Maybe there are artifacts of the old versions anywhere?

Comment: @Axel Richter thanks a lot for your help. Maybe old version in the local repository was the issue